# SQLite Count(column) GROUP BY issue

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I cannot figure out the following problem.
I am get a very simple table with a name column.
Now I want to count all the names inside this relation with the functionality below.

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(
            "select count(name) from geo group by name", null);
    int count = 0;
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        count = c.getInt(0);        
    }
    c.close();
    return count;
```

I see exactly two rows in my table.
One with name "John" the other with name "Sandra". But the code return always `count = 1`
If I execute the sql in my serverside application with mysql it runs fine.

Do you see the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want

```
 SELECT count(name) FROM geo
```

or

```
 SELECT count(DISTINCT name) FROM geo
```

Comment: Hi podiluska,
don't know if that is what I need. In my solution I will receive a number of names. But each name is grouped.
For that relation:
{
id:name
1 :John
2 :Sandra
3 :Sandra
}
my function must return 2.

Comment: But in your code, you're only reading the first row of the returned dataset.

Comment: the result can only be one row

Comment: Your current SQL will return more than one row.

Comment: @Beike: The second query return 2 for your example.